# Jq Grid Not showing Data

Tags: json, c#-4.0, jqgrid

I am converting Data Table to Json and setting it to jqgrid but it does not displaying Data

**JAVA Script**

$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/Approval/Home1",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['DayofMonth', 'DayofWeek', 'InTime', 'OutTime', 'Status'],
        colModel: [

```
        { name: 'DayofMonth', index: 'DayofMonth', editable: true },
        { name: 'DayofWeek', index: 'DayofWeek', editable: true },
        { name: 'InTime', index: 'InTime', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: "H:i " }, resizable: false },
         { name: 'OutTime', index: 'OutTime', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: "H:i " }, resizable: false },
      { key: false, name: 'Status', index: 'Status', editable: true }],


    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 31,

    loadonce: true,
    height: '100%',
    loadonce:true,
    width: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Employee Monthly Data',
    emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        Id: "0"
    },
    autowidth: true,
    autoheight: true,
    multiselect: false
}).navGrid('#pager', {
    edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true
}).navButtonAdd('#pager', {
    caption: "Edit",
    onClickButton: function () {
        var mygrid = $("#grid"), cellRowId = mygrid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow"), cellValue = mygrid.jqGrid("getCell", cellRowId, "EmployeeCODE")
        var div = $("#popup");
        div.load("/Definations/delCompany?id=" + cellValue, function () {
            div.dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 300,
                height: 350,
                title: "Change  Status.",
                resizable: false
            });
        });
    },
    position: "last"
});
```

});

**Here is Source**

```
 if (final.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    JSONString.Append("[");
                    for (int i = 0; i < final.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        JSONString.Append('{');
                        for (int j = 0; j < final.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (j < final.Columns.Count - 1)
                            {
                                JSONString.Append( final.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "=" + final.Rows[i][j].ToString() + ",");
                            }
                            else if (j == final.Columns.Count - 1)
                            {
                                JSONString.Append( final.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "=" + final.Rows[i][j].ToString() );
                            }
                        }
                        if (i == final.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            JSONString.Append('}');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JSONString.Append("}^");
                        }
                    }
                    JSONString.Append("]");
                }
                return JSONString.ToString();
```

**Here is JSon Part**

```
        var jsonData = ap.Data(am.code, month, year, lastday);



       var s= jsonData.Split('^').ToArray();



       int totalRecords = s.Count();

        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);


        var jsonData1 = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page,
            records=totalRecords,
            rows = s

        };



        return Json(jsonData1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: First of all, please, use correct terminology: "Jq Grid" and "jqgrid" should be jqGrid, "JAVA Script" -> JavaScript, Json -> JSON, "Data Table" -> table of database. Seconds you should *always* include, which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). If the version/fork is not important for you I recommend you to use free jqGrid 4.13.6 (see on NuGet [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/)).

Comment: is is showing and calculating all rows and pages but all cells are empty.

Comment: You use `loadonce:true`. Then you should return **all data at once**. No `totalPages` and `totalRecords` are required. The usage of `JSONString` is wrong too. If you have *the data* as `final.Rows` then you can use just `return Json(final.Rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. You need just describe more clear what information are in `final.Rows`. Do you have the same order of columns like in jqGrid or not?

Comment: Yes i have same order and same column name in final(Table) as i write in jqGrid

Comment: If you want to repair your car, then it's important to know which car you have: the producer, the model, the year of manufacturing and so on. If you have a BMW car, then it could be an electric car or diesel/petrol car. It could be a retro car or the newest model. The same information is important for jqGrid. It's not enough to write "i write in jqGrid". It's the same like I have BMW car. You have to write **which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid** (see my first comment).

Comment: Do you tried to use `return Json(final.Rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`? You could required (depend on the used jqGrid version) to remove `jsonReader` in the case.